# Session can not be resolved while calling session.getAttribute() method in jsp declation type

Tags: jsp

I am getting the error as "session can not be resolved" after calling session.getAttribute() method in jsp. Please suggest to resolve it. Thanks in advance.
The code is as below-

```
<%!
String getApplicantDetailsRow(ApplicantAdminViewTO viewTO, ResourceBundle labelResourceBundle, boolean actionNotepadModule,boolean directLettingModuleFlag,boolean canPrepareApplicantMatchList,boolean canViewOtherSubPortalApplicants,boolean canViewOtherSubPortalBids,boolean canViewAndEditOtherSubPortalApplicants,String strSaccCode){
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        PartnerTO partnerTO;
       <% CBLContext cblContext = (CBLContext) session.getAttribute(CBLConstants.CBLContext) %>;
        partnerTO = cblContext.getCBLPartner();
        long pid=partnerTO.getPartnerId();

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getSubPortalCode());
        strBuild.append(" / ");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.wrappingString(viewTO.getParentSystemId()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getUserId()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getFirstName()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getSurName()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkDateNull(viewTO.getDateOfBirth()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getAppCategoryCode()));
        if(!strSaccCode.equals("") && strSaccCode!=null){
           strBuild.append(strSaccCode);
        }
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkDateNull(viewTO.getQualifyingDate()));
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        if (pid==1023){
        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getApplicantStatus());
        strBuild.append("<br/>");
        strBuild.append("</td>");
        }else{
        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getApplicantStatus());
        strBuild.append("<br/>");
        strBuild.append(returnAppStatusButtons(viewTO, labelResourceBundle));
        strBuild.append("</td>");
        }

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getEligibleNoBedroom());
        strBuild.append(" / ");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getEligibleNoBedspace());
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getBandDesc());
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getCurrencyPoint());
        strBuild.append("</td>");

        if(actionNotepadModule){

            strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
            strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkDateNull(viewTO.getCaseLastReviewed()));
            strBuild.append("</td>");
        }

        strBuild.append("<td class=\"caption\">");
        strBuild.append("<input type=\"button\" name=\"");
        strBuild.append(LabelConstants.FULL_DETAIL);
        strBuild.append("\" value=\"");
        strBuild.append(labelResourceBundle.getString(LabelConstants.FULL_DETAIL));
        strBuild.append("\" onClick=\"formSubmit('");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getApplicantId());
        if(viewTO.getSubPortalCodeId()==secureUser.getSubPortalCodeTO().getSubPortalCodeId() || canViewOtherSubPortalApplicants || canViewAndEditOtherSubPortalApplicants){
            strBuild.append("')\" class=\"button\">");
        }else{
            strBuild.append("')\" class=\"graybutton\" disabled='disabled'>");      
        }

        strBuild.append("<input type=\"button\" name=\"");
        strBuild.append(LabelConstants.VIEW_BIDS);
        strBuild.append("\" value=\"");
        strBuild.append(labelResourceBundle.getString(LabelConstants.VIEW_BIDS));
        strBuild.append("\" onClick=\"formBid('");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getApplicantId());
        strBuild.append('\'');
        strBuild.append(',');
        strBuild.append('\'');
        strBuild.append( CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getFirstName()) );
        strBuild.append('\'');
        strBuild.append(',');
        strBuild.append('\'');
        strBuild.append(CBLUtil.checkNull(viewTO.getSurName()));
        //if(viewTO.getSubPortalCodeId()!=secureUser.getSubPortalCodeTO().getSubPortalCodeId() &&  !canViewOtherSubPortalBids){
        //  strBuild.append("')\" class=\"graybutton\" disabled='disabled'>");
        //}else{
            strBuild.append("')\" class=\"button\">");
        //}
        if(directLettingModuleFlag && canPrepareApplicantMatchList){ 
        strBuild.append("<input type=\"button\" name=\"");
        strBuild.append(LabelConstants.PREPARE_APPLICANT_MATCH_LIST_BUTTON);
        strBuild.append("\" value=\"");
        strBuild.append(labelResourceBundle.getString(LabelConstants.PREPARE_APPLICANT_MATCH_LIST_BUTTON));
        strBuild.append("\" onClick=\"prepareAppMatchList('");
        strBuild.append(viewTO.getApplicantId() );
        strBuild.append("')\" class=\"button\" style=\"width:180px;\" >");
        }

        return strBuild.toString();
    }

 %>
```

The error is -

An error occurred at line: 139 in the jsp file:

"session cannot be resolved"

line:139-`<% CBLContext cblContext = (CBLContext) session.getAttribute(CBLConstants.CBLContext) %>;`

Answer (score 0):

> "session cannot be resolved"

The `session` object in JSP is implicit object. You can use it only in scriptlets, it not available inside declaration (inside block `<%! ... %>`).